# Mandar datos a sql server

Tags: php, sql

Buen dia, tengo un problema con pasar datos en php para mandarlos a sql server, adjunto mi codigo:

Este es donde tengo mi tabla y mis input text, donde el  hace referencia a addDesktop.php para realizar el registro

desktops.inventory.php

```
<div id="desktop-inventory">
<div id="inventario-header">
    <form action="" id="search-bar" class="search-bar">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit" class="button" id="btn-search">Search</button>
    <button class="button" id="btn-clear">Clear</button>
    </form>
    <button class="button" id="btn-excel">Download Excel</button>
    <button class="button" id="btn-audit">Audit</button>
    <button class="button" id="btn-reload">Reload</button>
</div>

<div id="inventario-contenido">
    <form action="" method="POST" id="formulario" class="formulario">
        <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" placeholder="Brand">
        <input type="text" name="model" id="model" placeholder="Model">
        <input type="text" name="st" id="st" placeholder="Service TAG">
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Location">
        <input type="text" name="area" id="area" placeholder="Area">
        <input type="text" name="os" id="os" placeholder="OS">
        <input type="text" name="specs" id="specs" placeholder="Specs">
        <input type="text" name="hostname" id="hostname" placeholder="Hostname">
        <a id="add" href="../connection/addDesktop.php">ADD</a>
    </form>
    <table id="tabla" class="tabla">
        <tr>
            <th class="sorting">Brand</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Service Tag</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>OS</th>
            <th>Specs</th>
            <th>Hostname</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="datos-tabla">
    </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

Y este aqui es donde se debe hacer el registro, aun el codigo sql no esta completo estaba haciendo pruebas de conexion pero me genera un error con el campo brand

addDesktop.php

```
<?php
$serverName = "server\SQLTESTSVR";  
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ITSUPPORT", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"Pass");  

    $brand = $_POST['brand'];
    echo "La marca es: ".$brand;

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
if( $conn){  
     echo "Conexion exitosa.</br>";
}else{
    echo "Conexion fallo";
}
?>
```

La conexion a sql server si se realiza, hice la prueba sin asignar el valor a $brand pero ya cuando lo asigno me genera el siguiente error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: brand in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IT_SUPPORT\connection\addDesktop.php on line 5
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que realizar es agregar la ruta en la `action` de tu formulario ademas agregar un `boton` de tipo submit para enviar el formulario. lo que hacia era redireccionarte a la ruta pero no pasaba los datos.

Ejemplo:

```
<form action="../connection/addDesktop.php" method="POST" id="formulario" class="formulario">
        <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" placeholder="Brand">
        <input type="text" name="model" id="model" placeholder="Model">
        <input type="text" name="st" id="st" placeholder="Service TAG">
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Location">
        <input type="text" name="area" id="area" placeholder="Area">
        <input type="text" name="os" id="os" placeholder="OS">
        <input type="text" name="specs" id="specs" placeholder="Specs">
        <input type="text" name="hostname" id="hostname" placeholder="Hostname">
        <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias brother, funciono perfectamente

Comment: @CesarVillaseñor es un gusto aportar, una recomendación es utilizar ajax para evitar el recarga de pagina y así solo se realizaría peticiones

Comment: Podrias darme una idea de como seria mas o menos por favor?